# Probability of searching for a random key in random array using transpose sequential search?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I want to know how I can make the probability of A(i) (a random key) that is being sough be 1/(n^2) in transpose sequential search, where I have an array with random data. I want the search to always successful but the probability be 1/n^2.

Transpose sequential search (algorithm)
Definition: Search an array or list by checking items one at a time. If the value is found, swap it with its predecessor so it is found faster next time.

```
http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/transposeSeqSearch.html
```

Comment: (always successful) ==> (probability = 1) ... so what probability are we talking about?

Comment: You can use same idea to create a Search Heap, where most-searched items tend to have lower depth .. `P(find X) = { X exist? }`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Probability of a key being searched using linear search in random array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23209318/probability-of-a-key-being-searched-using-linear-search-in-random-array)

Comment: This is the same as your previous question, and it's still unclear what you're trying to accomplish.